# Semenantics help - PHP

Tags: php, this, variable-assignment

I have a code ('require_once' part does not matter):

```php
<?php
require_once('../shared/database.php');

class Administration{
    public $db;
    public $base;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db=new Database();
        $this->base=new stdClass();
        $this->base->url="http://".$_SERVER ['SERVER_NAME'].'/phpp/blog/admin/';
    }
}
?>
```

and code written below is implementing the code (written above).

```php
<?php
require_once('administration.php');

class Articles extends Administration{
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();} 

  $announcement='Some text.';           
  header('Location: '.$this->base->db.'articles.php?announcement='.urlencode($announcement));}
?>
```

Problematic part is `$this->base->db.`

If I change the `db` variable name to any other valid variable name, code still works but I am unable to find out why.

Does anybody know how it works?

Comment: `$this->base->db` is an **object**. Casting object to string, unless you have `__toString` method, is wierd. What do you expect by outputting `db` property?

Comment: And why do you use `$this->base->db` if you store url in `$this->base->url`? Do you have any idea what's going on in your code?

Comment: You're missing an opening quote on the `$announcement` line.

Comment: To u_mulder: I know db is an object but db (object) is $this->db variable and I wrote $this->base->db. You can also use $this->base->XYZ and it will be used value stored in $this->base->url.

Comment: U_mulder's second post reply: I won't ever used it. I have found it in learning book and I could not find out how it works.

Comment: To Anrea: Thank you, I have already corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

To me it appears that code has many typos. Perhaps error reporting isn't enabled for the environment because that code shouldn't work. The pseudo-variable `$this` is available within an object context.

```
<?php
require_once('administration.php');

$announcement='Some text.';
$administration = new Administration();
$location = sprintf('%sarticles.php?announcement=%s', $administration->base->url, urlencode($announcement));
header(sprintf('Location: %s', $location));
```

Comment: In fact I have tried to simplify the code for the reason of not rewritting tens of rows. So I will now correct the example by implementing constructor with parent cons. call.

Comment: For sure the code is working. I can post at some web storage zip file with whole code (from learning book). I have a theory that the operator **->** in fact is lamba so the compiler simple tipped that I want to call to _base->url_ variable because this is only var. containing (relevant) value in _base_ context.

Comment: I suspect that `$this->base->some_random_name` is null and location header looks like this `Location: articles.php?....`. In this scenario server will look for file under path from which it was request.

Comment: To Kaspars Primaks: That is an answer. In a mean while I will try to prove it.

Comment: To Kaspars Primaks: You were absolutely right. It works no matter of the examined variable.